# Are questions targeting non-standard computer platforms allowed/wanted?

Tags: discussion, rules, scope

My question is related to [this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/are-languages-targeting-fpgas-or-other-non-standard-non-sequential-computing-pla).

Are **questions/challenges** explicitly targeting non-standard computing platforms such as FPGAs allowed?

If yes: Are they wanted or welcome here or are they undesired?

Comment: Typically, you need a good reason to do it, but we've [allowed it at least once](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44381/automate-saving-the-world)

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, they are allowed, and welcome if interesting

Some examples:

- [Tetris in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11880/45941), one of our most well-received challenges, requires programming in Conway's Game of Life, which is certainly not a standard computing platform.
- [Automate saving the world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44381/45941) (as Nathan mentioned in a comment) requires the use of old (pre-1978) languages.